# fme datalist extension for alfresco community 4.0.c

Tags: alfresco, datalistitem

Hi I know that fme datalist extension is not fully compatible with community 4.0.c. But wanted to try it out. I installed the jar files and it seem to work fine for the datalists i had created earlier. But the side effect of this I noted, when i create a new site and send an invite to somebody, the ACCEPT or REJECT button does not show up in the tasks (for the invitee to accept or reject). Not sure what's going on.but a hint in the positive direction would help me debug? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finished migrating the fme datalists extensions to 4.0 this week. Fixed the issue you are referring to today. You might want to have a look at http://www.contentreich.de/alfresco-extended-datalists-migrated-to-4-0 and the source at github. Aside from https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-16153 and Solr issues with filtering, there are no more problems I am aware of. I think I'll be fixing the filtering to support solr based repos as well.