# How to get filtering to data lists in Alfresco Share (Community 4.0)

Tags: filtering, alfresco, alfresco-share

How to make filter by specific columns available to data lists in Alfresco Share? Version is Community 4.0. I've tried the existing solutions like fme datalist extension [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657557/fme-datalist-extension-for-alfresco-community-4-0-c) but it has some issues which require customizing the code more than I've got time and expertise. For instance, it loses all custom lists. I tried to add the list definitions from the XML configuration to the embedded definitions but it made the whole site crash.

Is there any other way to achieve filtering? The specific case is that I've got a list which has like ten or so columns. I want to make one or two of them filterable by providing a simple drop down menu of unique values.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not possible to filter data-list items out-of-the box in Alfresco Share. The FME extension is the only solution I have seen which will do that for you.

Comment: The problem with FME extension was that it didn't work with Community 4.0.x and/or custom lists. At least, it didn't work with my installation, and I tried to investigate and fix the code and XML definitions to make it work. I ended up creating a dirty hack with jQuery to achieve the functionality for fixed columns. It works for that specific case but it's not reusable or elegant.